# Using OpenVPN Connect in power saving mode

Tags: openvpn, power-options

On a Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0.1 I use OpenVPN Connect.

It works properly when the device is not in power saving mode. However when I turn the power saving on, the OpenVPN connection immediately becomes flaky. The client connects to the server, but after a few seconds it loses connection and tries to reconnect.

I have explicitly turned off OpenVPN Connect in "App power saving".

Is there anything I can do except for turning power saving mode off?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug or cause you turn on power saving mode it trys to shut down networks to save battery. power saving modes or app don't really save all that much so i'd just keep it off. Have you tryed a vpn app.

Answer (score 0):

For hotspot shield I have turned off "restrict all background data" on settings -> battery -> power saving mode!